# ERROR CON STRUCTS Y TEMPLATES C++

Tags: c++, lista, template, struct

Estoy aprendiendo listas enlazadas y quise intentar con templates, pero me da errores como:

> ```
> [Error] variable or field 'insertar',
> [Error] 'template<class T> struct nodo' used without template arguments declared void
> [Error] expected primary-expression before ',' token
> ```

Recién aprendo así que supongo son errores de declaración y uso de los templates con struct. Aquí el código:

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct nodo{
    T dato;
    nodo *siguiente;
};

template<class T>
void insertar(nodo *&,T);
void mostrar(nodo *);

int main(){
    nodo *lista=NULL;
    int n;
    cout<<"Cuantos numeros desea ingresar?: "; cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        float num;
        cout<<"Valor?: "; cin>>num;
        insertar(lista,num);
    }
    mostrar(lista);
    return 0;
}
template<class T>
void insertar(nodo *&lista,T n){
    nodo *n_nodo=new nodo();
    n_nodo->dato=n;
    nodo *aux1=lista;
    if(lista==aux1){
        lista=n_nodo;
    }
    n_nodo->siguiente=aux1;
}
void mostrar(nodo *lista){
    nodo *act= new nodo();
    act=lista;
    cout<<"\nLISTA: "<<endl;
    while(act!=NULL){
        cout<<act->dato<<"->";
        act=act->siguiente;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura `nodo` es una estructura plantilla, tal y como la has declarado:

```
template<typename T> // ¡Soy una plantilla! (template)
struct nodo ...
```

Las plantillas en C++ "*no existen*" hasta que no se instancian, el compilador para instanciarlas substituye todos los parámetros plantilla (en tu caso `T`) por aquellos argumentos que se le hayan pasado a la plantilla. Esto implica que las plantillas y sus parámetros van siempre juntos igual que las funciones y sus parámetros.

Por eso toda aparición de `nodo` sin un argumento será errónea: porque el compilador no sabrá con qué instanciar la plantilla.

```
template<class T>
void insertar(nodo *&,T); // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?
void mostrar(nodo *);     // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?

int main(){
    nodo *lista=NULL;     // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?

    ...
    ...

    return 0;
}

template<class T>
void insertar(nodo *&lista,T n){ // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?
    nodo *n_nodo=new nodo();     // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?

    ...

    nodo *aux1=lista;            // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?

    ...
}
void mostrar(nodo *lista){       // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?
    nodo *act= new nodo();       // ¿nodo? ¿nodo de qué?

    ...
}
```

Esto tiene fácil solución: díselo al compilador:

```
template<class T>
void insertar(nodo<T> *&,T);   // nodo de T
template<class ASEREJE>
void mostrar(nodo<ASEREJE> *); // nodo de ASEREJE

int main(){
    nodo<float> *lista=NULL;   // nodo de float

    ...
    ...

    return 0;
}

template<class T>
void insertar(nodo<T> *&lista,T n){ // nodo de T
    nodo<T> *n_nodo=new nodo<T>();  // nodo de T

    ...

    nodo<T> *aux1=lista;            // nodo de T

    ...
}
template <class ACHILIPU>
void mostrar(nodo<ACHILIPU> *lista){           // nodo de ACHILIPU
    nodo<ACHILIPU> *act= new nodo<ACHILIPU>(); // nodo de ACHILIPU

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que uses `nodo` debes incluir parámetros de template. Además, se debe incluir `template` en todas las funciones que hagan uso genérico del tipo `nodo`.

```cpp
template<class T>
void insertar(nodo<T>*, T);

template<class T>
void mostrar(nodo<T>*);
```